# how does erlang processes relate to gen behaviours

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

I would like to know how erlang processes are related to gen behaviours (gen_server, gen_fsm, gen_event). Like for example is a a gen_server a single process, group of processes or do they have no relation al all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different gen behaviours have different relations to processes. `gen_server` and `gen_fsm` have one process per instance (you can have multiple processes running the same `gen_server` code).  Whereas `gen_event` is running the handle_event callbacks synchronously in the context of the calling process (`gen_event:call`) or asynchronous in the context of the event manager process (`gen_event:notify`).

The gen behaviours are there to abstract away the concurrency and use processes to achieve this.  How they are doing this and if there is a 1:1 relationship between processes and gen behaviours depends on the implementation of the actual gen behaviour.

Comment: The event manager is one process and the gen_event handlers are run in that process irrespective of whether the event is generated by `gen_event:notify` or `gen_event:call`. It is similar to `gen_server:call` and `gen_server:cast`.

Answer (score 2):

A behavior such as `gen_server` is a single Erlang process executing a recursive function call in which the state of the behavior is stored. Please refer to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5796875/409228) to [Erlang/OTP behaviors for beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790804/erlang-otp-behaviors-for-beginner) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

gen_server is a 'behaviour'. It's some agreement about module structure. What functions are available in the module, what are signatures of that functions , what values they could return etc etc.

otp architecture assumes that some processes runs on that modules.

So we can say -- certain process is gen-server if it runs on module with gen_server behaviour, and was started by function, intended to start gen_server (start() or start_link() ).