# Calling handle_info from handle_cast/handle_call order of execution

Tags: erlang, gen-server

I have a `gen_server` and i do not understand the following:

```
-module(myserver).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-record(state,{ count=0}).

handle_cast(Message,From,State=#state{count=C})->
     self() ! something,
     {noreply,State}.
handle_info(Message,State=#state{count=C})
      NewCount=case Message of 
                   0 -> C+1;
                   true ->C,
      {noreply,State#state{count=NewCount}}.
```

Given the above code i want to understand the following thing:
-assuming i enter `handle_cast` and i send something to the `mailbox` of the gen_server which fits the `handle_info` case, will the `handle_info` get called on a different thread right then and there ( `self() ! Message` while i am still evaluating the `handle_cast`?

What is the order in which things unfold ?

- A

  - `handle_cast` enter
  - `handle_cast`  send to own mailbox
  - `handle_cast` returns
  - `handle_info` gets triggered
- B

  1. `handle_cast` enter
  2. `handle_cast` send to own mailbox
       3.`handle_info` gets triggered (concurrently) and may alter state
  3. `handle_cast` may or may not end before `handle_info` finishes , and can get state altered by `handle_info`

Comment: To improve your understanding of how `gen_server` works, consider reading [the `gen_server` behavior documentation](https://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/gen_server_concepts.html) and the answers to [Erlang/OTP behaviors for beginner](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5790804).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is A. All handlers of `gen_server` - like `handle_cast` or `handle_info` - are always executed in the same single process. The message send to self within `handle_cast` will be received by the `gen_server` implementation after the `handle_cast` callback returns. Only then `handle_info` will be called, and `handle_info` will receive the state returned from `handle_cast`.

Generally, all `gen_server` handlers are always called sequentially, and the state returned by a handler is passed to the handler which is called next.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that demonstrates that Wotek Surowka's answer is correct:

```
-module(s1).
-behavior(gen_server).
-compile(export_all).

start() ->
    gen_server:start_link(
      {local, ?MODULE}, 
      ?MODULE, 
      [],
      []
    ).

init(_Args) ->
    Count = 0,
    {ok, Count}.

handle_call(_Msg, _From, State) ->
    {reply, hello, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, Count) ->
    io:format("Entered handle_cast()...~n"),

    self() ! hello,
    timer:sleep(10000), % Sleep for 10 seconds

    io:format("Returning from handle_cast()...~n"),
    {noreply, Count+1}.

handle_info(Msg, Count) ->
    io:format("Entered handle_info(), Msg= ~w~n", [Msg]),
    io:format("Count in handle_info() is: ~w~n", [Count]),
    io:format("Returning from handle_info()...~n"),
    {noreply, Count}.

go() ->
    spawn(
      fun() -> gen_server:cast(?MODULE, "some message") end
    ),
    ok.
```

In the example above, `handle_cast()` sleeps for 10 seconds, so if `handle_info()` executed asynchronously, it would have plenty of time to display its output before `handle_cast()` returned.  Here are the results in the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs/gen_s/1server$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(s1).     
s1.erl:3: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,s1}

2> s1:start().
{ok,<0.71.0>}

3> s1:go().   
Entered handle_cast()...
ok  <--- return value of go()
Returning from handle_cast()...
Entered handle_info(), Msg= hello
Count in handle_info() is: 1
Returning from handle_info()...

4>
```

The output shows that `handle_info()` doesn't begin executing until after `handle_cast()` returns.

And, if you add some print statements to display the `pid` inside `handle_cast()` and `handle_info()`, you will see that the pid is the same:

```
-module(s1).
-behavior(gen_server).
-compile(export_all).

start() ->
    gen_server:start_link(
      {local, ?MODULE}, 
      ?MODULE, 
      [],
      []
    ).

init(_Args) ->
    Count = 0,
    {ok, Count}.

handle_call(_Msg, _From, State) ->
    {reply, hello, State}.

handle_cast(_Msg, Count) ->
    io:format("Entered handle_cast()...~n"),
    Self = self(),
    io:format("self() is: ~w~n", [Self]),

    Self ! hello,
    timer:sleep(10000), % Sleep for 10 seconds

    io:format("Returning from handle_cast()...~n"),
    {noreply, Count+1}.

handle_info(Msg, Count) ->
    io:format("Entered handle_info(), Msg= ~w~n", [Msg]),
    io:format("self() is: ~w~n", [self()]),
    io:format("Count in handle_info() is: ~w~n", [Count]),
    io:format("Returning from handle_info()...~n"),
    {noreply, Count}.

go() ->
    spawn(
      fun() -> gen_server:cast(?MODULE, "some message") end
    ),
    ok.
```

In the shell:

```
1> c(s1).     
s1.erl:3: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,s1}

2> s1:start().
{ok,<0.71.0>}

3> s1:go().   
Entered handle_cast()...
ok  <---return value of go()
self() is: <0.71.0>
Returning from handle_cast()...
Entered handle_info(), Msg= hello
self() is: <0.71.0>
Count in handle_info() is: 1
Returning from handle_info()...

4>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification !